# I can't Manage to close from in Python 3 with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to build a xml parser in python, i start to build gui framework, and here i need to create some forms to save some settings values. I manage to make it work and save some values to txt files for startup. But what ever i tried i can't manage to close the settings form when i click button. i need to close it with the x on the window. i can't find the root of the issue.

what i am trying to do is, when i click **Cancel**, form will be closed. if i click **Save**, form will first save data then close.

thanks a lot for your supports.

my code is as follows:

```
try:
    # for Python2
    print ("Importing for py2");
    from Tkinter import *   ## notice capitalized T in Tkinter
    import tkFileDialog
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    print ("Importing for py2 Failed !!!!");
    print ("Importing for py3");
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import filedialog
    from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
    from tkinter import messagebox



mainform = Tk()
mainform.minsize(300,100)
mainform.geometry('{}x{}'.format(800, 600))
mainform.title("OVF Template Parser - By Gurhan Cagin (R) 2018")

textPad = ScrolledText(mainform, width=100, height=80)
textPad.pack()

## functions and procdures
def donothing():
   x = 0

def quit():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you really want to quit?"):
        exit()

def about_command():
    label = messagebox.showinfo("About", "Nokia OVF Template Parser \nCopyright 2018 \nNo rights left to reserve")

def open_command():
        file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent=mainform, mode='rb', title='Select a file')
        if file != None:
            contents = file.read()
            textPad.insert('1.0',contents)
            file.close()

def SettingsFormFxn():
    settingsForm = Tk()
    settingsForm.minsize(300,100)
    settingsForm.geometry('{}x{}'.format(750, 550))
    settingsForm.title("Settings for the devault values")
    ## Frames
    top_frame = Frame(settingsForm, width = 740, height = 50, pady = 3)
    bottom_frame = Frame(settingsForm, width = 740, height = 50, pady = 3)



    settingsForm.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    settingsForm.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    top_frame.grid(row=0, sticky="ew")
    bottom_frame.grid(row = 4, sticky = "e")

    b1 = Label(top_frame, text = "CPU per Core in Ghz:")
    b1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    entryText = StringVar(settingsForm, "2.1")
    e1 = Entry(top_frame, textvariable = entryText, width = 5)
    e1.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

    def SaveFxn():
        with open("settings.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(e1.get() + "\n")
        ##f.write(ent2.get() + "\n")

    def CancelFxn():
        settingsForm.destroy


    cancel = Button(bottom_frame, text = "Cancel", command = CancelFxn, pady = 10, padx = 10,activebackground='grey',activeforeground='#AB78F1',bg='#e87474',highlightcolor='red')
    cancel.grid(row = 0, column = 10)
    save = Button(bottom_frame, text = "Save", command = SaveFxn, pady = 10, padx = 10)
    save.grid(row = 0, column = 11)


    settingsForm.mainloop()


## EOF FXNS

## Menu Definitions
menubar = Menu(mainform)

## File Menu
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Open", command = open_command)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command = quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

## Settings Menu
settingsmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
settingsmenu.add_command(label = "Settings", command = SettingsFormFxn)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings",menu=settingsmenu)

## About Menu
aboutmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
aboutmenu.add_command(label = "About", command = about_command)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=aboutmenu)


mainform.config(menu=menubar)
## EOF Menu Definitions


## Main loop
mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't call `Tk()` multiple times.  You need to use `Toplevel()` to create additional windows instead.

Comment: Don't make more than one `mainloop` I strongly suspect this causes your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot your parenthesis when trying to call settingsForm.destroy.

```
def CancelFxn():
    settingsForm.destroy()
```

Comment: Thats it, it worked like a charm, some times solution is so simple there but you need more carefull second eyes to see it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GurhanCagin _Most_ of the times however, creating a [mcve] by isolating the code that is reproducing the issue yields better perception to one's own eyes.